# how to add autcomplete to multiple inputs with codeigniter and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete, codeigniter-2

i have a form that contain 3 fields, each one of them i want to use jquery autocomplete to autocomplete all these fields for me. so i wrote this code

html

```
<input type='text' class='completeme' name='name'/>
<input type='text' class='completeme' name='job'/>
<input type='text' class='completeme' name='lasname'/>
```

js

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/autocomplete',
                data: { 'term': this.value},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

and added both to view, and created a controller named patients.php with controller autocomplete

Code

```
function Autocomplete(){
$this->load->model('Autocomplete');
    $term=$this->input->post('term');
    if(sizeof($term) > 2){      
        $options=array('table'=>'patients','field'=>'patient_name','term'=>$term);
        $q=$this->Autocomplete->GetAutocomplete($options);
        foreach($q as $q)$json[]=$q->patient_name;
        echo json_encode($json);
}
```

now my problem is

1. its not working :D.. when i check firebug post request it doesnt not
   post any values.
2. How can i pass in the autocomplete request the field name also along with the term its searching for ?
3. Is there any already existing codeigniter helper/custom lib that can
   do this in a cleaner way ?

thanks alot

Comment: can you post the actual firebug screenshot? Did it post to the correct page?(didn't get any 404 not found?)

Comment: yep i got correct url and no errors,yet my problem is that i want to pass the iput name along with its value in the $.ajax POST to the page, i tried "data: { term: this.term, name: $(this).attr('name') }" but it only send term var only, any clue how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you've got the correct url to post to.
Here's the problem I saw with your code:

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/autocomplete',
                data: { 'term': this.value}, <--you should not get the value here
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

It should be something like this:

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {
  var term = this.value; //get the value here
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/autocomplete',
                data: { 'term': term}, 
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

Also make sure that the json that is being returned is in the correct format so that jquery ui can read it.

Comment: yep i got correct url, my problem is that i want to pass the iput name along with its value in the $.ajax POST to the page, i tried "data: { term: this.term, name: $(this).attr('name') }" but it only send term var only, any clue how to fix it ?